# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error while inserting xml data into clob column

Tags: plsql

I have a procedure in a package to insert record to a table which takes a xml value in its param. The table has a column of CLOB datatype. I need to store xml data in that clob column. The insert statement works fine if the xml data is small, 
But if the xml data is large I get the above error.

```
PROCEDURE test
(
      p_id  IN Number,  
      p_clob IN Clob
);
```

Insert into test_table (id, clob_cloumn) values (p_id, p_clob);

Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to insert xml into Clob type column? You can either make XmlType Table Column or use some_xml_value.getclobval() method.